# Checkbox error message positioning, bootstrap + jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have built a form using bootstrap, I could make a validation for text boxes using jquery validation plugin, and used the errorPlacement to place the error in the last column in my design. But it doesn't work for checkboxes in my design, because the structure is not similar, how do we go around this issue?

Here's a jsfiddle for my code: https://goo.gl/dGRm0b

I am still new to bootstrap and jquery validator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an if/else statement to your errorPlacement to find a div to hold the error message for the checkboxes.

```js
 $.validator.addMethod("startsWithA", function(value, element) {
   return /^A/.test(value);
 }, "input must start with A");

 $('form').validate({

   rules: {
     fullname: {
       required: true,
       minlength: 5,
       maxlength: 10,
       startsWithA: true
     },
     resume: {
       required: true
     },
     language: {
       required: true
     }
   },
   messages: {
     fullname: {
       startsWithA: "my new message"
     },
     language: {
       required: "At least one language is required"
     }
   },

   highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
     $(element).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
   },
   unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
     $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
   },
   errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     if (element.attr("name") == "language") {
       error.insertAfter("#checkboxGroup");
     } else {
       error.appendTo(element.parent().next());
     }
   }
 });
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Basics</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="fullname">Full Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <input type="text" id="fullname" class="form-control" name="fullname" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="resume">Resume</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <input type="file" id="resume" class="form-control" name="resume" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="password">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="comments">Comments</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <textarea cols="40" rows="5" id="comments" class="form-control" name="comments"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Skills</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-7"> <span>Enter your programming languages</span>

          <div class="checkbox">
            <label for="csharp">
              <input type="checkbox" id="csharp" name="language" />C#</label>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label for="php">
              <input type="checkbox" id="php" name="language" />PhP</label>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label for="java">
              <input type="checkbox" id="java" name="language" />Java</label>
          </div>
          <div id="checkboxGroup"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10"> <span>Enter your level</span>

          <div class="radio">
            <label for="csharp">
              <input type="radio" id="beginner" name="level" />Beginner</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <label for="php">
              <input type="radio" id="intermediate" name="level" />Intermediate</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <label for="java">
              <input type="radio" id="expert" name="level" />Expert</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
          <input type="reset" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Reset" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```